# EL/JSP - Formatting number to apply currency, getting error

Tags: java, jsp, format, jstl, el

I have a tag that I am pulling from a Java class called "number". Say this has a value of 10. In my JSP page, I am trying to apply formatting to display it as $10.00. I've looked around for several ideas, although all I've found is what I have posted below, and I get the errors shown.

```
<label>Formatted Number:</label>
<span><fmt:formatNumber value="${number}" type="currency"></fmt:formatNumber>
    </span><br />
```

---

**Errors:**

(1) Element "fmt:formatnumber" not allowed as child of element "span" in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

(2) Element name "fmt:formatnumber" cannot be represented as XML 1.0.

---

This is nested within a 'span' and 'section' in the HTML (JSP) page.

Can anyone help me get around this? There has to be more than one way to do this.

Comment: Are you using the taglib directive at the top of your jsp?  `<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt" %>`